# How to use an action Listener for a button inside a while loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, while-loop, do-while

I'm making an auction game and i'm going to display an item for the user to bid on. if the user doesnt like that item, he bids for another item by clicking the next item button. Another item is then displayed. This is where the problem is. When i write a continue statement in the action listener for the button, it says continue cannot be used outside of a loop.

Comment: Your **code** please? Much will depend on your code, and your error and your not shown error message. Note that I very much doubt that you'll want to use a while loop in this situation. Instead you'll likely hold the items in a collection such as an ArrayList, have an int index variable, and increment the index when the button is pressed and then retrieve the next item in the collection using the newly advanced index.

Comment: Also, please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Again, I very much doubt that you'll want to use a while loop in this situation. Instead you'll likely hold the items in a collection such as an ArrayList or a simple array, have an int index variable, and increment the index when the button is pressed and then retrieve the next item in the collection using the newly advanced index. For example

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class NextItem extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] ITEMS = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed",
            "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };
    private JTextField displayField = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton nextBtn = new JButton(new NextAction("Next"));
    private int itemsIndex = 0;

    public NextItem() {
        displayField.setText(ITEMS[itemsIndex]);
        displayField.setFocusable(false);
        add(displayField);
        add(nextBtn);
    }

    private class NextAction extends AbstractAction {
        public NextAction(String name) {
            super(name); // give button its text
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);  // give button a hot key
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            itemsIndex++; // advance index
            itemsIndex %= ITEMS.length; // renormalize it -- set to 0 if too large
            displayField.setText(ITEMS[itemsIndex]);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        NextItem mainPanel = new NextItem();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NextItem");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try the code right away. Sorry for the delay